# mysql 8 is failure to start after upgrade from 5.7

Tags: upgrade, error-log, mysql-8.0, centos-7

I've upgraded one of the slave server from mysql 5.6 to 5.7 and now 5.7 to 8.
But after up-gradation steps done when i use systemctl start mysqld.service or systemctl restart mysqld facing error and mysql is not starting.
In error log i am getting following errors :

> 2019-01-16T15:32:05.808246Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.13) starting as process 22860
>
> 2019-01-16T15:32:14.328460Z 2 [ERROR] [MY-013140] [Server] Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'columnsname_ibfk' in the referenced table 'table_name'
>
> 2019-01-16T15:32:15.692313Z 2 [Warning] [MY-010772] [Server] db.opt file not found for test database. Using default Character set.
>
> 2019-01-16T15:32:15.975759Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010022] [Server] Failed to Populate DD tables.
>
> 2019-01-16T15:32:15.975874Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
>
> 2019-01-16T15:32:18.083808Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.13)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

If i can start mysql then i can run upgrade command to upgrade mysql :

mysql_upgrade -uroot -p****  --upgrade-system-tables

Comment: in place upgrade it always risky, check this - https://mysqlserverteam.com/upgrading-to-mysql-8-0-here-is-what-you-need-to-know/
because it is a One of the slave - make a clean install and check different upgrade strategy